# How do I use methods from a class that works in matlab and use it in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have defined a class that works in Matlab. I have to instantiate with values and I have 5 different objects. I want these objects in Simulink.
What I wanted to do was initialize them in a Matlab m file and have the objects in the workspace but I could not access them from the Simulink function block. What should I do?
I tried making a Matlab system block but that did not work.

basically what I want ( i have made an example of what class I have):

```
classdef ExampleClass
    %EXAMPLECLASS Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here
    
    properties
        Property1
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = ExampleClass(inputArg1)
            %EXAMPLECLASS Construct an instance of this class
            %   Detailed explanation goes here
            obj.Property1 = inputArg1 ;
        end
        
        function outputArg = method1(obj,inputArg)
            %METHOD1 Summary of this method goes here
            %   Detailed explanation goes here
            outputArg = obj.Property1*inputArg;
        end
    end
end
```

My class looks like something above. Because it is a big class with many methods I don't want it to run many times so I want to instantiate once.

```
P1=ExampleClass(1)
P2=ExampleClass(2)
P10=ExampleClass(10)
```

And then use the above objects in Simulink where the function argument is a value from Simulink so

```
function [y]=compute(x)


a(1)=P1.method1(x+2)
a(2)=P2.method1(x+2)
a(3)P10.method1(x+3)


y=mean(a)

end
```

How do I do this? I really hoped I could use my objects from workspace like some variables.
My question boils down to how do I use the class (that specific class as it is similar to mine) in simulink so I can use "P.method1(x)" where x is a value from simulink?

Comment: If you want to access variables from the workspace you need to declare them global, both in the workspace and in your function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo They are not variables I want to acsess but methods from objects.

Comment: Unless the methods are static, which they are not because they rely on `obj`, then you need an instance of the variable in the current workspace's scope in order to use its methods. So you _do_ want access to the object variables

Comment: @Wolfie Can you make a quick pseudo code of what you mean?

Comment: In your example you create `P1`, but then try and call `P1.method1()` in a function which has know visibility of `P1`. Either create `P1` inside the function, pass it into the function, or make it global (and declare it as global within the function)